# PostgreSQL - Combining multiple rows with several attributes into one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, greenplum

I have a table like this:

```
DATE        ID    ScoreA    ScoreB    ScoreC
20180101    001   91        92        25
20180101    002   81        82        35
20180101    003   71        52        45
20180102    001   82        15        66
20180102    002   69        67        77
...
20180131    003   88        65        73
```

Take a month data for example, I want to aggregate them into a report of MAX and MIN score with only one row for each `ID`. Just like:

```
ID    ScoreA       Date_A              ScoreB        Date_B            ...
001   MAX(ScoreA)  MAX(ScoreA).DATE    MAX(ScoreB)   MAX(ScoreB).DATE  ...
002   MAX(ScoreA)  MAX(ScoreA).DATE    MAX(ScoreB)   MAX(ScoreB).DATE  ...
003   MAX(ScoreA)  MAX(ScoreA).DATE    MAX(ScoreB)   MAX(ScoreB).DATE  ...
```

Where `MAX(ScoreA).DATE` means the `DATE` when the corresponding MAX or MIN score appeared (if the MAX score appeared on multiple dates, just pick one randomly)

Not like common seen combine-rows cases, it involves multiple columns at the same time. And since there will be **MANY** `ID`s and **HUNDREDS** of `Score`s (I mean there are `ScroeA` `ScroreB` ... `ScoreZ` ...  `Score1` `Score2` ... `Score100` ...), I hope to avoid using consuming operations, such as `JOIN` table.  So any good ideas?

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres? Those are two very different systems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe I write PostgreSQL in my Greenplum database. But I also believe this question may focus more on psql than GP.

Comment: "*I write PostgreSQL in my Greenplum*" does not make sense. Although Greenplum is based on Postgres it is something different and might not have some features modern Postgres versions provide. So by tagging both systems you risk getting answers that work in Postgres but not in Greenplum.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am seeking of a PostgreSQL script solving my problem, and in case of I can't reach some features, I also tag Greenplum to clarify my environment for any answerers' convenience.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I understand your point. Greenplum runs an older version of PostgreSQL. I just forget the exact version number so I take both tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid joins I'd offer such a construction

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DATE, ID, ScoreA, ScoreB, ScoreC,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by ScoreA desc) rnA,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by ScoreB desc) rnB,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by ScoreC desc) rnC,
    FROM ...
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN ... AND ...
), ids AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM cte
)
SELECT ID, 
    (SELECT ScoreA FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnA = 1) ScoreA, 
    (SELECT DATE FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnA = 1) Date_A,
    (SELECT ScoreB FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnB = 1) ScoreB, 
    (SELECT DATE FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnB = 1) Date_B,
    (SELECT ScoreC FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnC = 1) ScoreC, 
    (SELECT DATE FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rnC = 1) Date_C
FROM ids t
```

When you need date or some other attribute of max/min value it is reasonable to use row numbering instead of aggregating functions: `row_number() over (...) as rn` followed by condition `rn = 1`

**UPD**

As soon as @TaurusDang wants to have code generation, there is my solution to allow postgres to do almost all the work:

```
WITH cols AS
(
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
      AND table_name   = 'your_table'
      AND column_name like 'Score%'
)
-- first part: rows for cte subquery
SELECT ',row_number() over (partition by ID order by ' || column_name || ' desc) rn' || column_name
FROM cols
UNION ALL
-- second part: rows for final query
SELECT ',(SELECT ' || column_name || ' FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rn' || column_name || ' = 1) ' || column_name || ', (SELECT DATE FROM cte t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND rn' || column_name || ' = 1) Date_' || column_name
FROM cols
```

Just copy generated rows into the initial query: the first half to cte and the second one to the main query

Comment: Sorry for not stating my problem clear enough before. Since I would also need to deal with hundreds of score categories, it may be very hard for me to list all in SQL script one-by-one. Is there any way to also avoid such listing?

Comment: @TaurusDang I've updated the answer. Hope it'll  be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with max_score as
(
    Select    distinct id
        , max(ScoreA) over( partition by id ) as max_ScoreA
        , max(ScoreB) over( partition by id ) as max_ScoreB
        , max(ScoreC) over( partition by id ) as max_Scorec
    from TABLE_NAME
)
Select 
    cte.id
    , max_ScoreA, tbl_a.DATE
    , max_ScoreB, tbl_b.DATE
    , max_ScoreC, tbl_c.DATE
from 
max_score cte
join TABLE_NAME tbl_a
on cte.id = tbl_a.id
and cte.max_ScoreA = tbl_a.ScoreA
join TABLE_NAME tbl_b
on cte.id = tbl_b.id
and cte.max_ScoreB = tbl_b.ScoreB
join TABLE_NAME tbl_c
on cte.id = tbl_c.id
and cte.max_ScoreC = tbl_c.ScoreC
order by 1
```

Comment: Sorry for not stating my problem clear enough before. Since I would also need to deal with hundreds of score categories, it may be very hard for me to list all in SQL script one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another code-sample that will give you all the data you need:

```
select *
from (select
        distinct on (id) id,
        first_value(scorea) over w as a_min,
        last_value(scorea) over w as a_max,
        first_value(date) over w as a_min_d,
        last_value(date) over w as a_max_d
    from the_table
    window w as (partition by id order by scorea)
    order by 1,3 desc) a
join (select
        distinct on (id) id,
        first_value(scoreb) over w as b_min,
        last_value(scoreb) over w as b_max,
        first_value(date) over w as b_min_d,
        last_value(date) over w as b_max_d
    from the_table
    window w as (partition by id order by scoreb)
    order by 1,3 desc) b using(id)
join (select
        distinct on (id) id,
        first_value(scorec) over w as c_min,
        last_value(scorec) over w as c_max,
        first_value(date) over w as c_min_d,
        last_value(date) over w as c_max_d
    from the_table
    window w as (partition by id order by scorec)
    order by 1,3 desc) c using(id)
```

Note that there is 3 separate sub-queries, one for each score column. There is some *magic* going on here regarding [windowing-functions and partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) which would be useful to read up on. One tricky part here is that the various partitions would interfere with each other if put in the same query (at least on my pg 9.3.22).

Comment: Sorry for not stating my problem clear enough before. Since I would also need to deal with hundreds of score categories, it may be very hard for me to list all in SQL script one-by-one.